# vsCode fileWatcher multiple files moved

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks, file-watcher, vscode-api

I need to edit multiple files on their movement to a different path. Using vsCode fileWatcher is buggy because it sees each file movement as a separate event and fires the code inside simultaneously resulting in a buggy behavior where multiple files will become blank because of the logic I have inside of the watched and so on.. So is there a method or a logic to do smth different on multiple files simultaneous movement? Thanks